# Postgresql count in for loop

Tags: postgresql, loops, for-loop, count, plpgsql

How can we replace the plsql code with count to postgresql

```
FOR I IN 1..variable.count
Loop
Cr:= varray (i)
End loop;
```

Replacement for count in postgresql

Comment: [Looping through arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

Answer (score 1):

This can be executed like a normal query :
$$ declares a string works same as '' ,example: SELECT $$string$$; or SELECT $string$ 'text' $string$;
DO indicate the next string will be executed.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
rRecord RECORD;
tText TEXT ;
BEGIN 
FOR rRecord IN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM generate_series(1 , 10 , 1 ) 
LOOP 
tText := rRecord.count;
RAISE NOTICE 'Notice %',tText ;
END LOOP ; 
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```